# C# method doesn't appear to run

Tags: c#, unity-container

From `ReflectionHelper` in `Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension`...

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1062:ValidateArgumentsOfPublicMethods",
        Justification = "Validation done by Guard class")]
    public static TAttribute[] GetAttributes<TAttribute>(MemberInfo member, bool inherits) where TAttribute : Attribute
    {
        Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility.Guard.ArgumentNotNull(member, "member");

        IEnumerable<Object> attributesAsObjects = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), inherits);
        TAttribute[] attributes = new TAttribute[attributesAsObjects.Count()];

        int index = 0;
        attributesAsObjects.ForEach(attr =>
        {
            var a = (TAttribute) attr;

            attributes[index++] = a;
        });

        return attributes;
    }

public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

`attributesAsObjects` contains one element. `attributes` contains one element but it's `null`. The ForEach block (which I've expanded) doesn't appear to run - a breakpoint is not hit.

What is this witchcraft?

The [calling code](https://github.com/Chavoshi/Unity.NetCore/blob/9ccfc5173198fb7697ec018e141af2e134095308/Source/Unity.Interception/PolicyInjection/Policies/AttributeDrivenPolicy.cs), which results in a null reference exception on `attr`....

```
protected override IEnumerable<ICallHandler> DoGetHandlersFor(MethodImplementationInfo member, IUnityContainer container)
{
    if (member.InterfaceMethodInfo != null)
    {
        foreach (HandlerAttribute attr in ReflectionHelper.GetAllAttributes<HandlerAttribute>(member.InterfaceMethodInfo, true))
        {
            yield return attr.CreateHandler(container);
        }
    }
    foreach (HandlerAttribute attr in ReflectionHelper.GetAllAttributes<HandlerAttribute>(member.ImplementationMethodInfo, true))
    {
        yield return attr.CreateHandler(container);
    }
}
```

Here is `GetAllAttributes`... (Note the call to `ToArray` at the end.)

```
public static TAttribute[] GetAllAttributes<TAttribute>(MemberInfo member, bool inherits)
    where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Utility.Guard.ArgumentNotNull(member, "member");

    List<TAttribute> attributes = new List<TAttribute>();

    if (member.DeclaringType != null)
    {
        attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes<TAttribute>(member.DeclaringType.GetTypeInfo(), inherits));

        MethodInfo methodInfo = member as MethodInfo;
        if (methodInfo != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = GetPropertyFromMethod(methodInfo);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes<TAttribute>(prop, inherits));
            }
        }
    }
    attributes.AddRange(GetAttributes<TAttribute>(member, inherits));
    return attributes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Is the source code of the above code snippet somewhere available online?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is this witchcraft?

It's called "deferred execution" and basically means that if you don't actually enumerate an `IEnumerable<T>`, it's not executed.

To elaborate:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T item in enumeration)
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This method is *dangerous*. It lies to you. And it was used in a way that supports my theory: wrong.

```
new[]{ 6, 7 }.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

What does this line do? **Nothing**! Why? Because you'd need to *materialize* the result for it to actually execute any code:

```
new[]{ 6, 7 }.ForEach(Console.WriteLine).ToList();
```

*This* will print `6` and `7`.

Likewise, this code snippet:

```
attributesAsObjects.ForEach(attr =>
{
    var a = (TAttribute) attr;

    attributes[index++] = a;
});
```

does *nothing*. Because the result is not materialized, the code is simply not executed.

Comment: I've posted the calling code. Is the foreach loop not enumerating the IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: Your `ForEach` method is not executed, because it's result is never used. You'd need to materialize it's result (for example with a `.ToList()` call for it to *actually run*.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm talking about `attributesAsObjects.ForEach`

Comment: Yes, but is the calling code `DoGetHandlersFor` not materializing the collection or is this a bug in the framework?

Comment: Shouldn't a call to `ToArray` materialize the collection?

Comment: @IanWarburton Sure. But there is no such call here.

Comment: @nvoigt There is at the end of the missing method I've posted.

Comment: @IanWarburton It cannot be just *somewhere* in the code. `attributesAsObjects.ForEach` does simply drop it's result. That's why that  supposed loop in that method *never executes*.

Comment: @nvoigt It's not just somewhere in the code. It's on a collection which is constructed from the collection that has ForEach called on it. If that doesn't result in ForEach being called, then how else would a client of this framework materialise the collection?

Comment: @IanWarburton Does not matter. Read my first comment. I expanded my post accordingly.

Comment: What does not matter? If `ToArray` doesn't fully materialize a collection that has been constructed from calls to `AddRange`, then this is a bug as there's no way for a caller of `GetAllAttributes` to fully materialize the collection.

Comment: @IanWarburton I have no idea what part of the code you posted is "a framework". Calling `attributesAsObjects.ForEach` is a bug plain and simple, using that `ForEach` method is highly dangerous even if that specific bug is fixed in the future.

Comment: @IanWarburton for this code to work "as intended" you need to do `return attributesAsObjects.ForEach(...).ToArray()` and drop `attributes` variable. But better listen to this answer and instead delete `ForEach` function completely - it's dangerous and misleading.

Comment: It's in a Microsoft framework... https://github.com/unitycontainer/interception/blob/master/src/Utilities/ReflectionHelper.cs In fact, it's fixed in this version of the code!